# How to enable/disable subtitles in a VLCJ application

Tags: java, vlc, vlcj

In the VLC media player, it is possible to disable subtitles. It is unclear how to do that programmatically using VLCJ.

I have searched the Internet for information on how to do this, and could not find any information based on the current version of VLCJ. I did find some information, but the solutions shown are using API calls that apparently no longer exist in the current API.

How does one enable or disable subtitles in an application using the current vlcj? Can someone either provide the appropriate API call or (if the process is complex) point me to an example (using the *current* version of the API) of how to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With contemporary version of vlcj (4.7.x):

```java
mediaPlayer().subpictures().setTrack(subtitleTrackId);
```

Note the Javadoc on that method, you can not (reliably) just use track id 0, 1, 2, ..., you need to use the `trackDescriptions` method:

```java
List<TrackDescription> tracks = mediaPlayer().subpictures().trackDescriptions();
```

Iterate the track descriptions to find the track you want, and then get the id and pass it to the `setTrack` method described above.

To disable subtitles, pass the id of the track that has the "Disable" description.

https://javadoc.io/doc/uk.co.caprica/vlcj/latest/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/player/base/SubpictureApi.html

The API will change with vlcj 5.x and VLC 4.x when they are eventually released (the underlying native API dealing with track selection changed).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, please be advised: for the subtitled video I have I used the call you suggested. In my application the .subpictures().trackDescriptions() method returns an empty list. There is nothing for me to pass to setTrack(). I still cannot disable subtitles.

Comment: Are the subtitles baked in to the video? If so then you can't disable them of course.

Comment: Actually, when I run the video I am using in the VLC Player, I *can* disable the subtitles. The VLC Player "sees" 3 tracks: one for English subtitles, one for French subtitles, and one for Spanish subtitles. Apparently, by default, the player uses the English subtitles. I hit a menu item and those subtitles are disabled. VLCJ is apparently missing those titles.

Comment: IIRC track descriptions are not available until a media player elementary-stream-added-event of the relevant type is received, which will happen when you play the video. You can't do it in advance of playback. If not the elementary stream events, then the media-player-ready event.